# "Pointer being freed not allocated error"

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to run a function that deletes the nth element of the linked list (using zero-based indexing). Even though I don't have to necessarily malloc anything, I'm getting this error: "ev(10676,0x7fff73f9d300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fddc2404c10: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"

Here is the code:

```
typedef struct intlist intlist;

struct intlist {
int val;
intlist* next;


intlist* intlist_remove_nth(intlist *xs, unsigned int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (n == 1) 
    {
        intlist *tempremovefirst = xs->next;
        free(xs);
        return tempremovefirst;
    }
    intlist *temp = xs;
    for (temp = xs; i != n - 1; i++) 
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    intlist *temp2 = temp->next;
    temp->next = temp->next->next;

    free(temp2);
    return xs;
}

void evidence_intlist_remove_nth()
{
intlist *il1 = intlist_cons(1, NULL);
intlist *il2 = intlist_cons(4, il1);
intlist *il3 = intlist_cons(6, il2);
intlist *il4 = intlist_cons(8, il3);
intlist *il5 = intlist_cons(19, il4);
intlist *il6 = intlist_cons(24, il5);
intlist *il7 = intlist_cons(101, il6);
printf("expecting 101 24 19 6 4 1: ");
intlist_print(intlist_remove_nth(il7, 4));
printf("\n");
free(il1);
free(il2);
free(il3);
free(il4);
free(il5);
free(il6);
free(il7);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
evidence_intlist_remove_nth();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `free(il3);` It is twice `free`. (Also The index is different from the expected)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not mallocing the items on the list, you shouldn't be freeing them. `free()` is only used to free memory that has been returned by `malloc()` or one of its relatives.

Comment: I'm mallocing the items in the list in my main function. That's why I'm unsure why I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Just posted the rest of it!

Comment: I don't see intlist_cons.